# Subtracting datetimes in two different lists

Tags: python, list, datetime

Junior Dev here.

I'm looking to subtract two lists of date times. I'm encountering a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.datetime` Any suggestions on how to subtract these timestamps and print them?

My first list contains...

```
start_times = [datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 40, 757460), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 308809), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 322679), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 327886), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 329119), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 332553), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 335256), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 339678), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 353079), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 374466), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 387423), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 427936)]
```

My second list contains...

```
end_times = [datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 308804), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 322677), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 327884), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 329117), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 332551), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 335255), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 339676), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 353077), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 374465), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 387421), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 427935), datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 21, 13, 1, 48, 427937)]
```

I use the following to fill my lists respectfully...

```
start_times.append(datetime.now())
```

I have the following function that calculates the deltas in between and prints out the desired deltas. Note, that there is always a 1:1 relationship between start and end time.

```
def print_script_runtimes(start_times, end_times):
   for time in end_times:
       print(str(end_times[time] - start_times[time]))
```

Comment: That looks like a good start!  The for loop is wrong - the `time` variable actual contains each item in the list (one at a time as you go through the loop).  You may want to try enumerate() to get an index into the list or just a range.

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating over the *values* of `end_times`, not the indices.

Zip the lists together, then subtract the elements of the resulting tuples.

```
def print_script_runtimes(start_times, end_times):
    for start, end in zip(start_times, end_times):
        print(end - start)
```

You can also use `map` to apply `operator.sub` immediately.

```
from operator import sub


def print_script_runtimes(start_times end_times):
    for runtime in map(sub, end_times, start_times):
        print(runtime)
```

Comment: Cool use of zip() and map() - these are two functions that I haven't used a lot so I'm glad for the great examples.

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake in your code is that you are iterating over the values of `end_times`.

```py
def print_script_runtimes(start_times, end_times):
   for i in range(len(end_times):
       print(str(end_times[i] - start_times[i]))
```

EDIT: chepner's solutions are certainly better, despite the only error in your code being the one I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks for the call out. I knew I was close. Thank you @elidor00!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your 'for' loop. The way you wrote the code, the variable 'time' returns the datetime object in the list, not it's index. To get the index, you need something like this:

```
for i in range(len(endtimes)):
   print(str(end_times[i] - start_times[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using enumerate() as I suggested in my comment.  A range() example has been provided by others.

```
def print_script_runtimes(start_times, end_times):
   for x,time in enumerate(end_times):
       print(str(end_times[x] - start_times[x]))
       # alternatively:  print(str(time - start_times[x]))
```